# The best way to say *interesting* in Latin

Tags: adjective, vocabulary

It's sometimes difficult to convey some meaning in such an old language as Latin. I have trouble with the word *interesting*. I've heard someone say *iucundus* in this meaning, but it's not an accurate translation.

Neither is *attractivus* – being attractive is something else that being interesting.

Since the word seems very Latin – how should we translate it?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided some context.  The relationship between *interesting* and a Latin word may not be one-to-one, so (for example) providing some example sentences might be helpful.

Comment: From Strunk and White: "An unconvincing word; avoid it as a means of introduction. Instead of announcing that what you are about to tell is interesting, make it so." The solution is probably to be more specific about what's meant by "interesting" in that context.

Answer (score 12):

Well, *interesting* is actually quite Latin, given that it comes (I believe) from *interest*, which means (among other things), "it matters" or "it is of concern." So one way to do it would be to say *meá interest* ("it matters to me, it makes a difference to me"), but that doesn't have the positive connotations that "interesting" has.

Another way to say it—and the one I usually use (and have heard other Latin speakers use), given that it *does* have that positive connotation—is *studium excitat*, "it arouses eagerness/zeal/study."

Alas, if you're looking for an actual adjective, you may be SOL.

Comment: The verb _interest_ + pronoun is a good choice, I think, but you'll want to make sure that you use the ablative feminine possessive adjective (e.g., _mea_, _tua_) since _interest_ borrows its construction from _refert_. See Lewis and Short _intersum_ section III:Esp.: intĕrest, impers., it makes a difference, interests, concerns, imports; is of interest, importance; constr. with gen. pers. or meā, tuā, suā, and with a subj. or rel. clause,

Answer (score 10):

To add to Joel Derfner's suggestion of *studium excitat*:

Ovid *Ex Ponto* IV.3.35 *Excitat auditor studium,* "An audience stirs interest" ([translation source](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Latin/OvidExPontoBkFour.htm#anchor_Toc34218018)).

See also on the title of the Lutheran journal *Studium Excitare* ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studium_Excitare#Title)):

> "Studium Excitare" is a Latin phrase that means "to arouse zeal." The phrase is often used in historic Lutheran writings.

This is putting aside more specific descriptions such as *mirus*, *insolitus*, *visu/lectu/etc. dignus*, and as you say *iucundus*.

Answer (score 9):

The English `interesting` etymologically comes from Latin impersonal verb `meā/tuā/nostrā interest`, but in Latin it is a neutral way of saying `it is of interest/concern/importance` (for example, `tuā et meā maxime interest, te valere` Cic. Fam. 16, 4) and the expression does not have the vaguely positive connotations of English `interesting` (which can be applied to almost everything!).

The meaning of `interesting` may be subdivided into this (rough and by no means exhaustive) list:

1. Something that is pleasant to behold, to converse with, to read, etc. In this case `iucundus` is a good equivalent.
2. Something wonderful, strange, remarkable. `Mirus/mirandus` will do for this.
3. Something that moves and inspires, excites interest – in this case, `excitat studium [legendi/audiendi/scribendi ... ]` (for example, `Quamquam enim libri nostri complures non modo ad legendi, sed etiam ad scribendi studium excitaverunt` Cic. Off. 2.2.2.), `studium excitans`.

Answer (score 0):

This abstract concept is one that seems to be relatively rarely found compared to how common it is in English. Maybe it is cultural thing? Depending on the form of expression different words are found. For example, in the context of a state of mind the word *intersum* (to lie between) is sometimes used:

*Interest scire quale senatus consultum fuerit* ("It is interesting to know what kind of decree the senate made")

When we describe an object or thing as being interesting, then the adjective *iucundus* (as mentioned in other answers) is common. A similare adjective is *gratus*:

*sermones inferet vel gratos vel novos* ("It will introduce discussions that are interesting and novel")

Another possible adjective is *curiosus*. For example:

*Acci positum curiose* ("Accius has put in an interesting way") --Varro

Often the idea is expressed indirectly, such as by the gerundive:

*Prope oblitus sum quod maxime fuit scribendum* ("I almost forgot the most interesting thing of all", literally what must written) --Cicero

*quidquid visendum atque memorabile ex antiquitate duraverat* ("Whatever is interesting [=must be seen] and memorable which has lasted from antiquity")